# analyze-string: Nested to plain back to nested

Tags: regex, xslt

This may be an odd question but I am curious if there might be a solution. I have a deeply nested and complex XML-File, e.g. OOXML and I try to analyze its text with some regex.

To analyze the document's text I would like to (1) store all the text nodes in a variable, (2) run some regex and (3) write all the text nodes back to their origin elements. Obviously the last part is the problem and I have no idea if it is even possible.

(simplified) XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <p>
        <t>foo </t>
        <t>some text </t>
        <t>
            <i>number</i>
            <b>
                <nr>5</nr>
            </b>
        </t>
        <t>more </t>
        <t>text</t>
    </p>
</body>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:variable name="plain" select="normalize-space(string-join(t//text(), ''))"/>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$plain" regex="foo( .* )number (\d)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="'bar', regex-group(1), 'nr.', regex-group(2)"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Wanted output would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <p>
        <t>bar </t>
        <t>some text </t>
        <t>
            <i>nr. </i>
            <b>
                <nr>5</nr>
            </b>
        </t>
        <t>more </t>
        <t>text</t>
    </p>
</body>
```

I know that in this case a template matching on `t` and some XPath checking the `preceding` and `following` axes could do the job. But when the XML gets much more complicated, it is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="t[parent::p[matches(normalize-space(string-join(t//text(), '')), 'foo( .* )number (\d)')]]/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(., 'foo', 'bar'), 'number', 'nr.')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[ancestor::t]/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(., 'foo', 'bar'), 'number', 'nr.')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I do not know if this will still be applicable in complex XMLs.

Comment: Thank you! But I would like to have an opportunity to run regex over all nested text nodes in a element's subtree and write the changed text back into the original elements. Your stylesheet writes the wanted output, but it is more about using regex and the "back writing" part of my question.